# Sekhmet with the crown of Hathor?

Tags: egyptian, astrology

In the astronomical ceiling of the tomb of Seti (KV17) one of the columns is denoted by the figure of [Sekhmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sekhmet) wearing the crown of Hathor as below:

[image: Sekhmet]

What does this signify? Although Sekhmet is sometimes represented wearing the sun disk, it is never with the horns and always with the [uraeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uraeus). The sun disk between horns is the usual headress of [Hathor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hathor), not Sekhmet. Why is Sekhmet wearing the crown of Hathor in this particular context?

Comment: I'd venture a guess and say this could be a reference to the book of the divine cow. If memory serves, in the story Hathor took Sekhmet's form to destroy mankind in the service of Ra.

Answer (score 1):

### Sekhmet as the Bull Queen at the times of Seti's Reign

The Bull was an animal signifying the Sun and the Spring Equinox. 
It is a wild speculation that whenever Sekhmet-star ( inasmuch as Sirius is Isis, Io, Sothis, Dog-Star) was rising before Ra (Heliacal Rising) in the Spring morning, it signified the given ruler-ship.

You may find some clues in the Dendera Zodiac, perhaps Sekhmet was a presiding Goddess at the time of Seti's reign according to the Egyptian calendar? Seti I lived approximately 1294 BC to 1279 BC. I'm giving clues, not answers, it is way beyond my competence.

[image]

> Darnell, John Coleman. "[The Apotropaic Goddess in the Eye](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25152728?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)." Studien
>   Zur Altägyptischen Kultur 24 (1997): 35-48.